# How to avoid saving escape character (\) in db

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I'm using zend frame work zend form and zend db for my project.

The problem I have is, when the user enter some special characters in the text field (i.e "I'm"), it is saved in the database with the "\" character (i.e. "I\'").  I need to know how to fix this so it just saved as whatever the user entered.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable [magic-quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

If you cannot for any reason disable them you can use stripslashes to strip those \ when getitng the data out of the db before echoing it to the browser.

Comment: No, always decode early and encode late. Save the raw data in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stripslashes(trim($value));` to strip the `\` and remove the extra spaces.